# Is there a way to encrypt emailed information sent from Android or iOS?

Tags: android, ios, email, encryption

A friend of mine wants an app made in which users fill out information on their Android or iPhone (just basic stuff like name, contact information, etc), and that information is sent to an email address.

He also wants the emailed encrypted so that the vital information isn't somehow abused before it reaches the destination email.  Is there a specific command in Android on iOS programming that will encrypt details before sending, or is this automatically encrypted?

Comment: There are cryptographic methods on both of course. But you have to first know how to send that email, if encrypted text should be in attachment. What form will it have. And anyway, why email, when you can use https just the same way and with less effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world of email you're probably going to need to look into S/MIME. Now after you run away screaming, you will need to come up with a different plan. Take the requirements from your customer and ignore their technology advice. Then solve the problem.

[Using S/MIME to send encrypted mail on iOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4979?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

There is a good reason all email isn't encrypted already. It is a bag of hurt.

Comment: Bummmmmmerrr.  This project just got a little more complicated then, but that's okay (a challenge!).  Do you know an Android alternative?

Comment: It doesn't seem the support in Android is very good. I would suspect that is because in general encrypted email has never gained much traction.